# How to remove Duplicate LibreOffice 7.3.5.2 (Ubuntu & Manually Installed)

Tags: apt, uninstall, libreoffice, configuration

**Problem:** I have two of the same version of LO installed, Ubuntu and not-Ubuntu. How do I get rid of the Not-Ubuntu one?

**History:** I manually installed LibreOffice
(from a deb file if I remember right, and I presume using
`$ sudo dpkg -i *.deb`
) for an update, not knowing the mess it would make on top of the LO provided by Ubuntu.

(Then the U.LO broke styles, then it broke removing all styles with CTRL+M and I was pleased to have the old version (non-U) available. Now styles et al are fixed.)

But now I have two versions of LO. the Non-Ubuntu one runs real slow. -- Trouble is: it is the one that loads when I click on an .odt file (or other) in 'Files'. - I fixed the default program for the files, but leave it as a hint how the two installed on top of each other? --

I'd like to clean it up and have just the one LO provided by and integrated with Ubuntu.

The version info (from the Help Menu in both Writer-s) for each is:

```
Version: 7.3.5.2 / LibreOffice Community
Build ID: 30(Build:2)
CPU threads: 8; OS: Linux 5.4; UI render: default; VCL: gtk3
Locale: en-CA (en_CA.UTF-8); UI: en-US
Ubuntu package version: 1:7.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1
Calc: threaded
```

and

```
Version: 7.3.5.2 / LibreOffice Community
Build ID: 392c644e8a6d1ea0765aa2d613a91bcef808d6ea
CPU threads: 8; OS: Linux 5.4; UI render: default; VCL: gtk3
Locale: en-CA (en_CA.UTF-8); UI: en-US
Calc: threaded
```

**So Far:** I used Synaptic to remove all the 6.4 version and 6.x pieces.
Synaptic only shows one listing of LibreOffice all 7.3.5.2, all the Ubuntu installation.
There is no other listing of the other, manually installed, non-Ubuntu 7.3.5.2 installation, but it does have icons in 'Applications' and it does run, or rather walk (it's so slow.)

**Other Considerations:** I used LO a lot for crucial writing, and Thunderbird for email. I don't really have time to reconfigure PPG and styles and keyboard shortcuts and Calc-Base databases for mail-merges and and and.

**Summary**: How to undo the double install without having to reconfigure LO from scratch?

**Default Program Solved**: How to set all LO files to load in the Ubuntu version only? OK I figured that out for a few crucial file types. Listed as possible default programs are for example *LibreOffice Writer* and *LibreOffice 7.3 Writer* But still I'd like to be rid of the dupicate LOs.

**Further Ideas**

I could uninstall using Synaptic and or

```
sudo apt-get autoremove -y libreoffice-\*
```

But would that uninstall both?
Would I loose all my customizations?

In Ubuntu Applications lists the Ubuntu simply as LibreOffice and Writer etc.
Ubuntu Applications lists the other as LibreOffice 7.3, Writer 7.3...

**Further:**
This is similar to what Synaptic shows in that all entries are Ubuntu versions, for example
[libreoffice-base-core 1:7.3.5.-rc2-Oubun 1:7.3.5.-rc2-Oubun office productivity suite-shared library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nk0xa.png)

```
$ dpkg --list | grep libreoffice*
ii  liblibreoffice-java                       
1:7.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1            all          LibreOffice
UNO runtime environment -- Java library rc 
libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer     
1:7.2.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1            amd64        transitional
package for GStreamer backend for LibreOffice ii  libreoffice-base    
1:7.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1            amd64        office
productivity suite -- database ii  libreoffice-base-core              
1:7.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1            amd64        office
productivity suite -- shared library ii  libreoffice-base-drivers     
1:7.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1            amd64        Database
connectivity drivers for LibreOffice ii  libreoffice-calc             
1:7.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1            amd64        office
productivity suite -- spreadsheet ii  libreoffice-common              
1:7.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1            all          office
productivity suite -- arch-independent files ii  libreoffice-core     
1:7.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1            amd64        office
productivity suite -- arch-dependent files ii  libreoffice-draw       
1:7.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1            amd64        office
productivity suite -- drawing ii  libreoffice-gnome                   
1:7.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1            amd64        office
productivity suite -- GNOME integration ii  libreoffice-gtk3          
1:7.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1            amd64        office
productivity suite -- GTK+ 3 integration ii  libreoffice-help-common  
1:7.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1            all          office
productivity suite -- common files for LibreOffice help ii 
libreoffice-help-en-us                    
1:7.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1            all          office
productivity suite -- English_american help ii  libreoffice-impress   
1:7.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1            amd64        office
productivity suite -- presentation ii  libreoffice-java-common        
1:7.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1            all          office
productivity suite -- arch-independent Java support files ii 
libreoffice-math                          
1:7.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1            amd64        office
productivity suite -- equation editor ii  libreoffice-nlpsolver       
0.9+LibO7.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1      all          "Solver for Nonlinear Programming" extension for LibreOffice ii 
libreoffice-ogltrans                      
1:7.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1            all          transitional
package for libreoffice-ogltrans ii  libreoffice-report-builder       
1:7.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1            all          LibreOffice
component for building database reports ii 
libreoffice-report-builder-bin            
1:7.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1            amd64        LibreOffice
component for building database reports -- libraries ii 
libreoffice-script-provider-bsh           
1:7.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1            all          BeanShell
script support provider for LibreOffice scripting framework ii 
libreoffice-script-provider-js            
1:7.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1            all          JavaScript
script support provider for LibreOffice scripting framework rc 
libreoffice-script-provider-python         1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.18.04.1   
all          Python script support provider for LibreOffice scripting
framework ii  libreoffice-sdbc-firebird                 
1:7.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1            amd64        Firebird SDBC
driver for LibreOffice ii  libreoffice-sdbc-hsqldb                   
1:7.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1            amd64        HSQLDB SDBC
driver for LibreOffice ii  libreoffice-sdbc-mysql                    
1:7.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1            amd64        MariaDB/MySQL
SDBC driver for LibreOffice ii  libreoffice-sdbc-postgresql           
1:7.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1            amd64        PostgreSQL
SDBC driver for LibreOffice ii  libreoffice-style-colibre             
1:7.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1            all          office
productivity suite -- colibre symbol style ii 
libreoffice-style-elementary              
1:7.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1            all          office
productivity suite -- Elementary symbol style rc 
libreoffice-style-tango                   
1:7.2.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1            all          transitional
package for Tango symbol style ii  libreoffice-style-yaru             
1:7.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1            all          office
productivity suite -- Yaru symbol style ii  libreoffice-wiki-publisher
1.2.0+LibO7.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1    all          LibreOffice extension for working with MediaWiki articles ii  libreoffice-writer  
1:7.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1            amd64        office
productivity suite -- word processor
```

Further Info (though not helpful I'm afraid)

```
$ which soffice
/usr/bin/soffice

$ whereis soffice
soffice: /usr/bin/soffice
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. No the duplicates do not show up. That is the problem, along with that there still are two versions installed. See the versions from the Help-About Menu of Writer above.

Comment: Please show us the complete output of `which soffice` and `whereis soffice`. Both should show up on one of the outputs; figure out which one you want to remove.

Comment: Use code formatting for command output, please, not quote formatting. Quote formatted output is very hard to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Success:** The unwanted Libreoffice version was a snap installation.
To remove it

```
sudo snap rm - r   libreoffice
```

It was visible with whereis only from the admin user. Thank you user535733 for that idea.

```
MaOlComp:~$ whereis libreoffice
libreoffice: /usr/bin/libreoffice /usr/lib/libreoffice /etc/libreoffice /usr/share/libreoffice /snap/bin/libreoffice.math /snap/bin/libreoffice.calc /snap/bin/libreoffice.writer /snap/bin/libreoffice.base /snap/bin/libreoffice /snap/bin/libreoffice.impress /snap/bin/libreoffice.filebug /snap/bin/libreoffice.draw /usr/share/man/man1/libreoffice.1.gz
```

So there is a snap version of LibrOffice, it does run (though with errors see the command below that ran it) and it is the unwanted one (as per the Help-About Info), the not-Ubuntu version!

```
MaOlComp:~$ /snap/bin/libreoffice.writer
Gtk-Message: 11:33:37.575: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: 11:33:37.576: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Failed to open config file '/usr/share/libexttextcat/fpdb.conf'
Failed to open config file '/usr/share/libexttextcat/fpdb.conf'
Failed to open config file '/usr/share/libexttextcat/fpdb.conf'
```

The idea for Synaptic with `pkexec synaptic` still did not display the snap package version.

The help I found at Linuxhint.com on how to remove a snap package on Ubuntu
https://linuxhint.com/remove-snap-package-ubuntu/
suggested the directories needed to be removed with a second command

`sudo snap rm - r  [app]`

but this was not the case.

Comment: I had to use `sudo snap remove libreoffice`, but that did the trick. It didn't know what `rm` or `-r` were.

Answer (score 0):

Launch Synaptic with `pkexec synaptic`. In the lower left corner of Synaptic select *Status* as shown in the below screenshot. In the upper left corner of Synaptic select *Installed (local or obsolete)*. The LibreOffice packages that you want to remove will be listed in the top center pane of Synaptic which is currently empty in the below screenshot.

[image]

To remove a package in Synaptic right-click the package and from the context menu select *Mark for Removal*. Removing the libreoffice-core package will also remove the entire locally installed LibreOffice suite which depends on it.